# $\gcd(p_{n-1}, \ n^5 - n^3 + n^2 - n + 1) = 1$ where $p_n = n$th prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

How can I prove in general that, for all $n\geq 2$:

$$
\gcd(p_{n-1}, \ n^5 - n^3 + n^2 - n + 1) = 1
$$

Seems to always be true:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.ntheory.generate import prime


def f(n):
    return n**5 - n**3 + n**2 - n +  1

for n in range(3, 100000000):
    p = prime(n-1)
    d = gcd(f(n), p)
    if d != 1:
        print (n)
```

Assume true.

$$
f(X) = X^5 - X^3 + X^2 - X + 1
$$

is irreducible and modulo each prime, i.e. $f(n+1) \neq 0 \pmod {p_n}$ so that $\prod_{j=2}^n\overline{f(j+1)} \in $ the units of $\Bbb{Z}/2 \times \Bbb{Z}/3 \times \Bbb{Z}/5 \times \dots $

So far it seems like the polynomials $g(X) = f(X \pm 1)$ are such that $g(n) \neq 0 \pmod {p_n}$

Comment: I see this as a coincidence (what's the chance of the polynomial evaluated at n divisible by the n-th prime?).

Comment: @KennyLau try other polynomials with the code.  They don't show the same result.

Comment: For example?$ $

Comment: just prove that $k \not | n^5-n^3+n^2-n+1$ in the range $k \in [(n-1)(\ln(n-1)+\ln \ln (n-1) -1) , (n-1)(\ln(n-1)+\ln \ln (n-1) )] and $k$ is integer.

Comment: @Ahmad I'm more of an algebra person.  Do you have more of the algebro-style of proof?

Comment: Why calculate the gcd? $p_{n-1}$ is a prime, it's a divisor of $f(n)$ or not.

Comment: @ProfessorVector it just came out that way because I was playing around with $\gcd$.

Comment: @EyesOnBud number theory tag =)

Comment: @mathreadler what's that you mean?

Comment: Number theory questions seem to be popular.

Comment: i did not solve it in the comment nor mentioned any thing useful to a proof, in general most of the questions in NT that include both $p_n,n$ are hard to solve and the majority of these question are open problems ,because $p_n$ behave an a very irregular way relevant to $n$.

Comment: Enjoy math, please see my answer to your question.

Comment: Normally $n<p_{n-1}$, suppose $ n = p_{n-1} -r$ or $n≡ (-r) mod( p_{n-1})$ then we may write:

$N=n^5 -n^3 + n^2 -n +1 ≡ ( -r^5 +r^3 +r^2 + r +1 ) mod (p_{n-1})$

Now $p_{n-1}$ can divide N if we have:


 $(r^2 +1)(r+1)-r^5 ≡ 0 mod (p_{n-1}) $

or:
 
$(r^2 +1)(r+1) ≡ r^5 mod (p_{n-1}) $ 

Since $( r, r+1) = 1$ also $(r, r^2 +1)=1$, this congruence has no integer solution that is $p_{n-1} $ and N has no common divisor.

Note that this argument can not be generalized for any prime; for example for $n=4$ we get $N=973$ which is divisible by $p_4=7$

Comment: underrated question +1

Comment: @mick why is it underrated?

Comment: @mick curious, do you see an application for it?

Comment: I can't figure out now what I wrote at the end of the post.  Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: @mick, this polynomial is quite random and arbitrary, you should try out other formulas!   I sort of must massaged some starting polynomial into shape until it worked out

Comment: @Daniel, "underrated" is just a fashionable way to say that you like something or that it deserves more attention. There's rarely any deep meaning behind the word in context of how it's used on internet these days.

Comment: We have one (arbitrary/unmotivated) quantity per prime and we want to know how often that quantity is divisible by its prime. The probabilistic heuristic is that the $p$-quantity is divisible by $p$ with probability $\frac1p$. Since $\sum_p \frac1p$ diverges, the natural conjecture is that there will be infinitely many times when the divisibility holds, though the examples will be extremely sparse. Look into "Wieferich primes" for another example of this phenomenon.

Comment: @DanielDonnelly the powers are all noncomposite powers, and all coefficients are $-1,+1$ and the degree is low. You might have found it by some luck but it is certainly not a coincidence ! <imo>

Comment: Make sure that your programming language calculates n^5 correctly if n is the 100 millionth prime (pn is about 2^24, the 5th power is 2^120). Otherwise your result might be nonsense.